# the type initialize for "OlampiadEbtedaee.NeedFunction" threw an exception

Tags: c#

The following is my code(C# windowsForm). When I am publish my project, in other computers I am getting the error/ exception:

> The type initializer for 'OlampiadEbtedaee.NeedFunction' threw an exception.

i call this class's functions (NeedFunction) in main form-load event. Could the problem be because im using microsoft.win32?? or because accessing to registery failed in other computer??

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.Win32;
  using System.IO;
  namespace OlampiadEbtedaee
  {
 public static class NeedFunctions
{
   public static bool IsStringInFile(string fileName, string searchString)
   {
       return File.ReadAllText(fileName).Contains(searchString);
   }

   ////////////////////////////////////////
   public static string TaskbarsizeState()
   {
       RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced", false);
       String value = myKey.GetValue("TaskbarSizeMove").ToString();
       return value;
   }

   public static string PaintStatusBarState()
   {
       RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\paint\view", false);
       String value = myKey.GetValue("ShowStatusBar").ToString();
       return value;
   }

   public static string magnifierState()
   {
       RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\ScreenMagnifier", false);
       String value = myKey.GetValue("ZoomIncrement").ToString();
       return value;
   }
   public static string taskbarSizeMove = TaskbarsizeState();
   public static string paintStatusBarState = PaintStatusBarState();
   public static string getMagnifierZoomState = magnifierState();



   public static string GetPathOfWallpaper()
   {
       string pathWallpaper = "";
       RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", false);
       if (regKey != null)
       {
           pathWallpaper = regKey.GetValue("WallPaper").ToString();

           regKey.Close();
       }
       return pathWallpaper;
   }

   public static void CreatePrequires()
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\D");
       Directory.Delete(@"D:\D");
       Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\F");
       Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\X");
   }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is about you do not check whether the registry keys exist, and access their values.
create registry keys first and then run your project, your problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

You do not check whether the registry keys exist, and access their values.

Since the methods are called as initializers of static member variables, the type cannot be initialized, and therefore startup fails

Comment: please explain more. What should I do?

Comment: in my laptop it works fine and no error, but in others i get error